# I want to add rows to a ROWSOURCE automatically whenever i add new data

Tags: excel, vba

hope you're doing well.
I'm having a problem regarding the addition of new rows to a rowsource in VBA excel.
To put this in context, I have a Combobox that has multiple products, and each one is priced differently.
I want to add a command button which allows me to add new products to that Combobox alongside the pricing elements.

('[Calculette_form.xlsm]Calcul'!$T7:$T64)  this is the rowsource, I want that whenever I add a new product, the ($T64) would move automatically to ($T65) and so on
I need your help, I'm kinda stuck here. Hope my explanation is clear (hope the picture will help)

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried count() before, Do loop...nothing really made sense.
I just need the proper coding solution for it.

Comment: How is the row source set now ? Is it with some vba code or manual ?

Comment: manual , from the rowsource property

Comment: If the data for the combo is on a worksheet then you could turn that into a table (`Ctrl+T`), reference the data from the table in a named range and use the named range as the RowSource.  Whenever you add a new item to the table it will be picked up by the named range and show in the combobox.

Comment: I second Darren here, the best way to do this is to leverage tables, and use a table range as the source.

Comment: Unrelatedly, you should really _name_ all these project components.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource)
    UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = "'[Calculette_form.xlsm]Calcul'!" & _
              rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count).Address(0, 0)
              
End Sub
```

Comment: I just need one more thing, now I want to add a new product just by clicking on that command button. I'm thinking of adding a user form that contains all pricing elements and submitting their values then I want them to appear directly in the source. Hope i didn't confuse you

Comment: @AnouarALMOUSLIH Write them to the sheet and expand the range to suit,

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking about. But is there any way I can add them to the sheet just by a command button? Cause I protected the sheet and it's just a lot of work to reopen it every time.

Comment: @AnouarALMOUSLIH You can [unprotect/protect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.unprotect) the sheet with a line of code in the macro.

Comment: yea bro, I already did that. But for this particular macro, I just want to add products without having to reopen the sheet cause it's all made on a form.

Comment: @Anouar I don't know what "without having to reopen the sheet" means. I suggest you post another question with further details of your existing code.

Comment: hey bro, I figured out the solution to my problem. The only thing I'm still struggling with is that whenever I run the code u gave me and close the form it doesn't save the changes. It goes back to its initial source. is there anything I can do?

Comment: @Anouar You need to put some code in UserForm_Initialize() to set the rowsource dynamically rather than the default property value